# stripes RedirectResolution redirecting to https url

Tags: java, https, stripes

Lets say the user access a stripes action1 using https. Once action1 processing is complete, it uses RedirectResolution to redirect to action2. At this point, the browser receives a 302 to to action2 with http and not https. How will I make RedirectResolution to use https while redirecting to action2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may need to implement you're own [Resolution](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/action/Resolution.html) for this. For example:

```
return new Resolution() {
    public void execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.sendRedirect("https://example.com/target.action");
    }
};
```